# modulo not returning correct value

Tags: java, modulo

My piece of code :

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(count == 1){
            // Reading via bufferedReader


            int resultNumber = 0;
            if (nthModifier == 0) {
                System.out.println("0");
            } else if (nthModifier == 1) {
                System.out.println("0 1");
            } else {
                int a = Integer.valueOf(nextLineString[0]);
                int b = Integer.valueOf(nextLineString[1]);
                int c = Integer.valueOf(nextLineString[2]);
                for (int i = kPreviousNumbers; i < nthModifier; i++) {
                    int nextNumber = Math.floorMod(Math.floorMod(a , 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(b , 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(c, 1000000007), 1000000007);
                    resultNumber = nextNumber;
                    a = b;
                    b = c;
                    c = nextNumber;
                }
            }

            System.out.print(resultNumber + " ");

        }
        count++;
    }

}
```

The test case says that the `10th modified Fibonacci number will be 845114970`. But what ever I do I end up getting 923527, I am trying to multiply in batches of three, the concept is same like fibonacci series, but instead of adding, I am multiplying with set of three numbers. Is there something I am missing while applying the modulo?

Comment: Integer overflow?

Comment: To avoid that I have also tried this `int nextNumber = Math.abs((Math.abs(a % 1000000007) * Math.abs(b % 1000000007) * Math.abs(c % 1000000007)) % 1000000007);`

but still it returns : 273406272, the 10th modified Fibonacci number . 

expected : 10th modified Fibonacci number : 845114970

Comment: you missed one modulo.

Answer (score 1):

You used : `(a * b * c)` = `( (a % mod) * (b % mod) * (c % mod) ) % mod`..

If `(a % mod)` &  `(b % mod)` & `(c % mod)` be large number ex. `(mod-1)` then there will be overflow and you don't get correct result. To avoid this overflow u need to do this:

`( a * b * c ) % mod` = `( ( (a % mod) * (b % mod) ) % mod ) * (c % mod) ) % mod`

Change this:

```
Math.floorMod(Math.floorMod(a , 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(b , 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(c, 1000000007), 1000000007);
```

To

```
Math.floorMod(Math.floorMod(Math.floorMod(a , 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(b , 1000000007), 1000000007) * Math.floorMod(c, 1000000007), 1000000007);
```

Comment: Isn't there still a problem here with `(a % mod) * (b % mod)`? You've fixed that in an answer to a different question.. or does that not apply here?

Comment: how there is problem?

Comment: ((a%mod) * ( b%mod))%mod

Comment: (1000000007*1000000007) < 2^63

Comment: if (mod-1)*(mod-1) is greater than 2^63 then you need to implement multiply with modulo by summation

Comment: i just show you how modulo work. its simple you need to take long